# How to use Google Home local fulfilment on more than 1 hub?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-smart-home

I am having multiple hubs( several ESP8266s with relays) in my home. I am trying to enable local fulfilment on these hubs.
Everything is working fine for a single hub but when I use multiple hubs, I am only able to listen to HTTP data on one hub.

Is there any way I can enable local fulfilment on all the hubs?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple hubs in parallel is not supported currently in the Google Home ecosystem for the same smart home action . If you want this feature to be include you can raise a feature request in our [public issue tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/). This will help us prioritize our development road map.